# Large Community Clustered Network Formatting

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I created this visual of a network using:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[adjmatrix, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Is there a good way to expand the nodes away from each other so that the clustering isn't so tight, or a way to organize the vertex labels better.

Comment: Can you share the data so people can play around with different solutions?

Comment: the data is a 530 x 530 adjacency, I don't really know how to share that? With my very limited knowledge of stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be way too many labels to fit in the area provided, so I think you *must* make the image much larger while keeping the vertex (and label) size small, e.g.

```
CommunityGraphPlot[
  adjmatrix,
  VertexSize -> Small,
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  ImageSize -> 3000
]
```