# How to label a large number of vertices using a list of names

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using `CommunityGraphPlot` on a network with 500ish nodes. I am defining the graph using a variable `adjmatrix` which is the adjacency matrix of the network. Right now the nodes are just named by number. I have a list `vertexnames` where the index of each entry is that number node. How do I use `CommunityGraphPlot` so that each vertex is labelled with the corresponding name in  `vertexnames`?

Comment: What do you get from `Options[CommunityGraphPlot]`?

Comment: The relevant Option seems to be `VertexLabels` although I don't know how to assign them to the list entries.

Comment: Neither do I, but I'd start with smaller examples to figure out the syntax, or look at the help page to see if it gives examples on `VertexLabels`

Comment: Is this not practically [the same question you posted yesterday](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136067/27951), but with fewer details?

Comment: I intended this one to be about how to label the vertices and the one yesterday to be about the display size. I cannot figure out the syntax for labelling vertices, even after looking through the documentation on Wolframs site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on [`VertexLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabels.html) and [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).

Here's an example—first we create an example graph with no human readable vertex names and a list of names:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];
names = VertexList[g];
g = IndexGraph[g];
```

Then label the nodes:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, VertexLabels -> Thread[VertexList[g] -> names]]
```